# Tabs and Carousel in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, tabs, carousel

I want to implement tabs and inside the tabs route to a carousel.Can anybody provide me the code sample as I am new to Angular JS and have issues implementing routing inside tabs in Angular JS.Here bootstrap can also be used in Angular JS.

Comment: Do you know http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/?

Answer (score 0):

ng-view is not good for you maybe as you can have only 1.
try to take a look at ui-view in angularUI project to enable multiple views with sub views.
as for carousel and tabs, you got implementation for that with angularUI/bootstrap/jqueryUI so no need to implement by yourself.